# how to share textarea content with twitter?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter

I need to share content of a `<textarea>` via twitter. I have a js function quotes(), which generates a random quote and this html:

```
<textarea id="txtbox" style="width:600px; height: 50px;" ></textarea>

 <button onClick="quotes()">Click Here</button>
```

Below I need a twitter share button, like this:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button"{count} data-url="goo.gl/udj2qQ" data-text= '' >Tweet</a>
```

but in the data-text section I need my quote.

Comment: Could you add the ***quotes*** function content ? Could you be more precise on what you exactly want ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to remove the old button, create a new one and run the `tweeter` sdk code again using `twttr.widgets.load();`

> More information:
>
> - https://dev.twitter.com/web/tweet-button/javascript-create
> - https://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript/initialization

```js
function quotes() {
  var txt = document.querySelector('textarea').value;
  var tbutton = document.querySelector('.twitter-share-button');
  
  tbutton.parentNode.removeChild(tbutton);
  
  var newA = document.createElement('a');
  newA.setAttribute('href', 'https://twitter.com/share');
  newA.setAttribute('class', 'twitter-share-button');
  newA.setAttribute('data-url', 'goo.gl/udj2qQ');
  newA.setAttribute('data-text', txt);
  document.body.appendChild(newA);
  twttr.widgets.load();
}
```

```html
<textarea id="txtbox" style="width:600px; height: 50px;"></textarea><br />
<button onClick="quotes()">Click Here</button>
<hr />
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button"{count} data-url="goo.gl/udj2qQ" data-text="blabla">Tweet</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
```

http://jsbin.com/wonasi